# Android sending open mp4 (videocamera) file to server

Tags: java, android, sockets, seek, mediarecorder

do you know if there is a possibility to start sending the video file created by mediarecorder while it's still recording?
The scenario looks something like this:
I'm recording video to the local file and after a while I want to make a copy on a remote server. Can I create a socket, take the FileDescriptor from the file and push there the stream? There are still issues with non-seekable sockets. Is it possible, when the operation is over, to copy the beginning of the file to use it's header in the file on the remote server?